# How to convert Microsoft Locale ID (LCID) into language code or Locale object in Java

Tags: java, windows, locale, lcid

I need to translate a [Microsoft locale ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx), such as 1033 (for US English), into either an [ISO 639 language code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639) or directly into a Java [Locale](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) instance. (Edit: or even simply into the "Language - Country/Region" in Microsoft's table.)

Is this possible, and what's the easiest way? Preferably using only JDK standard libraries, of course, but if that's not possible, with a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it started to look like there is no ready Java solution to do this mapping, we took the ~20 minutes to roll something of our own, at least for now.

We took the information from the horse's mouth, i.e. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx, and copy-pasted it (through Excel) into a .properties file like this:

```
1078 = Afrikaans - South Africa
1052 = Albanian - Albania
1118 = Amharic - Ethiopia
1025 = Arabic - Saudi Arabia
5121 = Arabic - Algeria 
...
```

(You can download the file [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2896691/stack/lcid-codes.properties) if you have similar needs.)

Then there's a very simple class that reads the information from the .properties file into a map, and has a method for doing the conversion.

```
Map<String, String> lcidToDescription;

public String getDescription(String lcid) { ... }
```

And yes, this doesn't actually map to *language code* or *Locale object* (which is what I originally asked), but to Microsoft's "Language - Country/Region" description. It turned out this was sufficient for our current need.

Disclaimer: this really is a minimalistic, "dummy" way of doing it yourself in Java, and obviously keeping (and maintaining) a copy of the LCID mapping information in your own codebase is not very elegant. (On the other hand, neither would I want to include a huge library jar or do anything overly complicated just for this simple mapping.) So despite this answer, **feel free to post more elegant solutions or existing libraries** if you know of anything like that.

Comment: Mapping using English-only names may cause problems. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958178/in-java-is-there-any-way-to-get-a-locale-given-its-display-name/958600#958600

Comment: In general that's true - but for our particular case those language/country names in English are fine (we're pulling some software information out of an SCCM database, and simply want something more human-readable than the numeric codes)

Answer (score 6):

You could use [GetLocaleInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318101(VS.85).aspx) to do this (assuming you were running on Windows (win2k+)).

This C++ code demonstrates how to use the function:

```
#include "windows.h"

int main()
{
  HANDLE stdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == stdout) return 1;

  LCID Locale = 0x0c01; //Arabic - Egypt
  int nchars = GetLocaleInfoW(Locale, LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME, NULL, 0);
  wchar_t* LanguageCode = new wchar_t[nchars];
  GetLocaleInfoW(Locale, LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME, LanguageCode, nchars);

  WriteConsoleW(stdout, LanguageCode, nchars, NULL, NULL);
  delete[] LanguageCode;
  return 0;
}
```

It would not take much work to turn this into a [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) call. (Tip: emit constants as ints to find their values.)

Sample JNA code:

- [draw a Windows cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739870/extract-cursor-image-in-java/740528#740528)
- [print Unicode on a Windows console](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/java-unicode-on-windows-command-line.html)

Using JNI is a bit more involved, but is manageable for a relatively trivial task.

At the very least, I would look into using native calls to build your conversion database. I'm not sure if Windows has a way to enumerate the LCIDs, but there's bound to be something in .Net. As a build-level thing, this isn't a huge burden. I would want to avoid manual maintenance of the list.

Comment: Thanks! In our case the code needs to run on other platforms (e.g. Linux) too, even though the information we're handling is Windows-centric and comes from an SCCM database. But maybe in some cases this is the best option - I do agree that it's not nice to have to maintain the mappings in a file (even if they rarely change). Btw, if anyone considers doing this using the Windows API, this might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000723/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-call-a-windows-kernel-function-from-java

Answer (score 2):

The following code will programmatically create a mapping between Microsoft LCID codes and Java Locales, making it easier to keep the mapping up-to-date:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * @author Gili Tzabari
 */
public final class Locales
{
    /**
     * Maps a Microsoft LCID to a Java Locale.
     */
    private final Map<Integer, Locale> lcidToLocale = new HashMap<>(LcidToLocaleMapping.NUM_LOCALES);

    public Locales()
    {
        // Try loading the mapping from cache
        File file = new File("lcid-to-locale.properties");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file))
        {
            properties.load(in);
            for (Object key: properties.keySet())
            {
                String keyString = key.toString();
                Integer lcid = Integer.parseInt(keyString);
                String languageTag = properties.getProperty(keyString);
                lcidToLocale.put(lcid, Locale.forLanguageTag(languageTag));
            }
            return;
        }
        catch (IOException unused)
        {
            // Cache does not exist or is invalid, regenerate...
            lcidToLocale.clear();
        }

        LcidToLocaleMapping mapping;
        try
        {
            mapping = new LcidToLocaleMapping();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // Unrecoverable runtime failure
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
        for (Locale locale: Locale.getAvailableLocales())
        {
            if (locale == Locale.ROOT)
            {
                // Special case that doesn't map to a real locale
                continue;
            }
            String language = locale.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
            String country = locale.getDisplayCountry(Locale.ENGLISH);
            country = mapping.getCountryAlias(country);
            String script = locale.getDisplayScript();
            for (Integer lcid: mapping.listLcidFor(language, country, script))
            {
                lcidToLocale.put(lcid, locale);
                properties.put(lcid.toString(), locale.toLanguageTag());
            }
        }

        // Cache the mapping
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file))
        {
            properties.store(out, "LCID to Locale mapping");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // Unrecoverable runtime failure
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param lcid a Microsoft LCID code
     * @return a Java locale
     * @see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223140.aspx
     */
    public Locale fromLcid(int lcid)
    {
        return lcidToLocale.get(lcid);
    }
}

import com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import com.google.common.collect.SetMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.bitbucket.cowwoc.preconditions.Preconditions;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 * Generates a mapping between Microsoft LCIDs and Java Locales.
 * <p>
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32324060/14731
 * @author Gili Tzabari
 */
final class LcidToLocaleMapping
{
    private static final int NUM_COUNTRIES = 194;
    private static final int NUM_LANGUAGES = 13;
    private static final int NUM_SCRIPTS = 5;
    /**
     * The number of locales we are expecting. This value is only used for performance optimization.
     */
    public static final int NUM_LOCALES = 238;
    private static final List<String> EXPECTED_HEADERS = ImmutableList.of("lcid", "language", "location");
    // [language] - [comment] ([script])
    private static final Pattern languagePattern = Pattern.compile("^(.+?)(?: - (.*?))?(?: \\((.+)\\))?$");
    /**
     * Maps a country to a list of entries.
     */
    private static final SetMultimap<String, Mapping> COUNTRY_TO_ENTRIES = HashMultimap.create(NUM_COUNTRIES,
        NUM_LOCALES / NUM_COUNTRIES);
    /**
     * Maps a language to a list of entries.
     */
    private static final SetMultimap<String, Mapping> LANGUAGE_TO_ENTRIES = HashMultimap.create(NUM_LANGUAGES,
        NUM_LOCALES / NUM_LANGUAGES);
    /**
     * Maps a language script to a list of entries.
     */
    private static final SetMultimap<String, Mapping> SCRIPT_TO_ENTRIES = HashMultimap.create(NUM_SCRIPTS,
        NUM_LOCALES / NUM_SCRIPTS);
    /**
     * Maps a Locale country name to a LCID country name.
     */
    private static final Map<String, String> countryAlias = ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder().
        put("United Arab Emirates", "U.A.E.").
        build();

    /**
     * A mapping between a country, language, script and LCID.
     */
    private static final class Mapping
    {
        public final String country;
        public final String language;
        public final String script;
        public final int lcid;

        Mapping(String country, String language, String script, int lcid)
        {
            Preconditions.requireThat(country, "country").isNotNull();
            Preconditions.requireThat(language, "language").isNotNull().isNotEmpty();
            Preconditions.requireThat(script, "script").isNotNull();
            this.country = country;
            this.language = language;
            this.script = script;
            this.lcid = lcid;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode()
        {
            return country.hashCode() + language.hashCode() + script.hashCode() + lcid;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj)
        {
            if (!(obj instanceof Locales))
                return false;
            Mapping other = (Mapping) obj;
            return country.equals(other.country) && language.equals(other.language) && script.equals(other.script) &&
                lcid == other.lcid;
        }
    }
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LcidToLocaleMapping.class);

    /**
     * Creates a new LCID to Locale mapping.
     * <p>
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs while reading the LCID table
     */
    LcidToLocaleMapping() throws IOException
    {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223140.aspx").get();
        Element mainBody = doc.getElementById("mainBody");
        Elements elements = mainBody.select("table");
        assert (elements.size() == 1): elements;
        for (Element table: elements)
        {
            boolean firstRow = true;
            for (Element row: table.select("tr"))
            {
                if (firstRow)
                {
                    // Make sure that columns are ordered as expected
                    List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>(3);
                    Elements columns = row.select("th");
                    for (Element column: columns)
                        headers.add(column.text().toLowerCase());
                    assert (headers.equals(EXPECTED_HEADERS)): headers;
                    firstRow = false;
                    continue;
                }
                Elements columns = row.select("td");
                assert (columns.size() == 3): columns;
                Integer lcid = Integer.parseInt(columns.get(0).text(), 16);
                Matcher languageMatcher = languagePattern.matcher(columns.get(1).text());
                if (!languageMatcher.find())
                    throw new AssertionError();
                String language = languageMatcher.group(1);
                String script = languageMatcher.group(2);
                if (script == null)
                    script = "";
                String country = columns.get(2).text();
                Mapping mapping = new Mapping(country, language, script, lcid);
                COUNTRY_TO_ENTRIES.put(country, mapping);
                LANGUAGE_TO_ENTRIES.put(language, mapping);
                if (!script.isEmpty())
                    SCRIPT_TO_ENTRIES.put(script, mapping);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the LCID codes associated with a [country, language, script] combination.
     * <p>
     * @param language a language
     * @param country  a country (empty string if any country should match)
     * @param script   a language script (empty string if any script should match)
     * @return an empty list if no matches are found
     * @throws NullPointerException     if any of the arguments are null
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if language is empty
     */
    public Collection<Integer> listLcidFor(String language, String country, String script)
        throws NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException
    {
        Preconditions.requireThat(language, "language").isNotNull().isNotEmpty();
        Preconditions.requireThat(country, "country").isNotNull();
        Preconditions.requireThat(script, "script").isNotNull();
        Set<Mapping> result = LANGUAGE_TO_ENTRIES.get(language);
        if (result == null)
        {
            log.warn("Language '" + language + "' had no corresponding LCID");
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        if (!country.isEmpty())
        {
            Set<Mapping> entries = COUNTRY_TO_ENTRIES.get(country);
            result = Sets.intersection(result, entries);
        }

        if (!script.isEmpty())
        {
            Set<Mapping> entries = SCRIPT_TO_ENTRIES.get(script);
            result = Sets.intersection(result, entries);
        }
        return result.stream().map(entry -> entry.lcid).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    /**
     * @param name the locale country name
     * @return the LCID country name
     */
    public String getCountryAlias(String name)
    {
        String result = countryAlias.get(name);
        if (result == null)
            return name;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bitbucket.cowwoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>preconditions</artifactId>
        <version>1.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Usage:

```
System.out.println("Language: " + new Locales().fromLcid(1033).getDisplayLanguage());
```

will print "Language: English".

Meaning, LCID 1033 maps to the English language.

**NOTE**: This only generates mappings for locales available on your runtime JVM. Meaning, you will only get a subset of all possible Locales. That said, I don't think it is technically possible to instantiate Locales that your JVM doesn't support, so this is probably the best we can do...

Answer (score 0):

[The was the first hit on google](http://www.brawer.ch/software/fonts/doc/gnu/java/awt/font/opentype/NameDecoder.html) for "Java LCID" is this javadoc:

```
gnu.java.awt.font.opentype.NameDecoder
```

> private static java.util.Locale
>   getWindowsLocale(int lcid)
>
> ```
> Maps a Windows LCID into a Java Locale.
>
> Parameters:
>     lcid - the Windows language ID whose Java locale is to be retrieved. 
> Returns:
>     an suitable Locale, or null if the mapping cannot be performed.
> ```

I'm not sure where to go about downloading this library, but it's GNU, so it shouldn't be too hard to find.

Comment: We found that too, but it looks rather suboptimal solution for this - it's a "utility class that helps with decoding the names of *OpenType and TrueType fonts*". And looking at the source, the conversion methods seem to be quite lacking - it only knows how to map a couple of the most common locales!

Comment: Here's the source: http://classpath.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.91/NameDecoder_8java-source.html See the method which "Maps a Windows LCID into a Java Locale", and note the comment "FIXME: This is grossly incomplete." :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script to paste into the F12 console and extract the mapping for the currently 273 languages to their lcid (to be used on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c):

```js
// extract data from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c
const locales = {}, dataTable = document.querySelector('div.table-scroll-wrapper:nth-of-type(2)>table.protocol-table'); 
for (let i=1, l=dataTable.rows.length; i<l; i++) {
    const row = dataTable.rows[i]; 
    let locale = Number(row.cells[2].textContent.trim());  // hex to decimal
    let name = row.cells[3].textContent.trim();  // cc-LL
    if ((locale > 1024) && (name.indexOf('-') > 0))  // only cc-LL (languages, not countries)
        locales[locale] = name; 
} 
console.table(locales);  // 273 entries
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easily possible with Apache POI using the [org.apache.poi.util.LocaleID](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/util/LocaleID.html) class.

Java Locale to LCID:

```
LocaleID.lookupByLanguageTag(new Locale("en", "US").toLanguageTag()).getLcid()
```

LCID to Java Locale:

```
new Locale(LocaleID.lookupByLcid(1033).getLanguageTag())
```