# How to get keyboard layout name from a keyboard layout identifier?

Tags: c#, .net

My application has to display all the installed input languages in the system and the keyboard layouts against each input languages.

For example:

```
   [InputLaguage]
    Tamil
      [Keyboard layouts]
        US
        Murasu Anjal
        Tamil
    English
        US
```

We can get installed language identifiers and keyboard layout identifiers from the

```
  GetKeyboardLayoutList(User32.dll)
```

`API function by splitting LWORD and HWORD.`

But I didn’t find a way to get a keyboard layout name from the keyboard layout identifier.
From the above example, I have to get the `US, Murasu Anjal and Tamil against Tamil language.`

Please help…

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's not a complete answer for your question, but here's a good chunk of it that took me a couple of hours to compile by hand.   It's a mapping of every layout code to the layout name that my version of Windows 7 had available.  I had to type the names by hand, so excuse any typos there.  The codes were gathered programatically.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace DesktopDictation.DeviceButtonMappings
{
  public class KeyboardLayout
  {
    const int KL_NAMELENGTH = 9;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern long GetKeyboardLayoutName(StringBuilder pwszKLID); 

    //each keyboard layout is defined in Windows as a hex code
    public static string GetLayoutCode()
    {
      var name = new StringBuilder(KL_NAMELENGTH);
      GetKeyboardLayoutName(name);

      return name.ToString();
    }

    //This is a mapping table from hex to descriptive name
    public static String MapLayoutName(string code = null)
    {
      if (code == null)
        code = GetLayoutCode();

      switch (code)
      {
        case "0000041C":
          return "Albanian";
        case "00000401":
          return "Arabic (101)";
        case "00010401":
          return "Arabic (102)";
        case "00020401":
          return "Arabic (102) Azerty";
        case "0000042B":
          return "Armenian eastern";
        case "0001042B":
          return "Armenian Western";
        case "0000044D":
          return "Assamese - inscript";
        case "0000082C":
          return "Azeri Cyrillic";
        case "0000042C":
          return "Azeri Latin";
        case "0000046D":
          return "Bashkir";
        case "00000423":
          return "Belarusian";
        case "0000080C":
          return "Belgian French";
        case "00000813":
          return "Belgian (period)";
        case "0001080C":
          return "Belgian (comma)";
        case "00000445":
          return "Bengali";
        case "00010445":
          return "Bengali - inscript (legacy)";
        case "00020445":
          return "Bengali - inscript";
        case "0000201A":
          return "Bosnian (cyrillic)";
        case "00030402":
          return "Bulgarian";
        case "00000402":
          return "Bulgarian(typewriter)";
        case "00010402":
          return "Bulgarian (latin)";
        case "00020402":
          return "Bulgarian (phonetic)";
        case "00040402":
          return "Bulgarian (phonetic traditional)";
        case "00011009":
          return "Canada Multilingual";
        case "00001009":
          return "Canada French";
        case "00000C0C":
          return "Canada French (legacy)";
        case "00000404":
          return "Chinese (traditional) - us keyboard";
        case "00000804":
          return "Chinese (simplified) -us keyboard";
        case "00000C04":
          return "Chinese (traditional, hong kong s.a.r.) - us keyboard";
        case "00001004":
          return "Chinese (simplified, singapore) - us keyboard";
        case "00001404":
          return "Chinese (traditional, macao s.a.r.) - us keyboard";
        case "00000405":
          return "Czech";
        case "00020405":
          return "Czech programmers";
        case "00010405":
          return "Czech (qwerty)";
        case "0000041A":
          return "Croatian";
        case "00000439":
          return "Deanagari - inscript";
        case "00000406":
          return "Danish";
        case "00000465":
          return "Divehi phonetic";
        case "00010465":
          return "Divehi typewriter";
        case "00000413":
          return "Dutch";
        case "00000425":
          return "Estonian";
        case "00000438":
          return "Faeroese";
        case "0000040B":
          return "Finnish";
        case "0001083B":
          return "Finnish with sami";
        case "0000040C":
          return "French";
        case "00011809":
          return "Gaelic";
        case "00000437":
          return "Georgian";
        case "00020437":
          return "Georgian (ergonomic)";
        case "00010437":
          return "Georgian (qwerty)";
        case "00000407":
          return "German";
        case "00010407":
          return "German (ibm)";
        case "0000046F":
          return "Greenlandic";
        case "00000468":
          return "Hausa";
        case "0000040D":
          return "Hebrew";
        case "00010439":
          return "Hindi traditional";
        case "00000408":
          return "Greek";
        case "00010408":
          return "Greek (220)";
        case "00030408":
          return "Greek (220) latin";
        case "00020408":
          return "Greek (319)";
        case "00040408":
          return "Greek (319) latin";
        case "00050408":
          return "Greek latin";
        case "00060408":
          return "Greek polyonic";
        case "00000447":
          return "Gujarati";
        case "0000040E":
          return "Hungarian";
        case "0001040E":
          return "Hungarian 101 key";
        case "0000040F":
          return "Icelandic";
        case "00000470":
          return "Igbo";
        case "0000085D":
          return "Inuktitut - latin";
        case "0001045D":
          return "Inuktitut - naqittaut";
        case "00001809":
          return "Irish";
        case "00000410":
          return "Italian";
        case "00010410":
          return "Italian (142)";
        case "00000411":
          return "Japanese";
        case "0000044B":
          return "Kannada";
        case "0000043F":
          return "Kazakh";
        case "00000453":
          return "Khmer";
        case "00000412":
          return "Korean";
        case "00000440":
          return "Kyrgyz cyrillic";
        case "00000454":
          return "Lao";
        case "0000080A":
          return "Latin america";
        case "00000426":
          return "Latvian";
        case "00010426":
          return "Latvian (qwerty)";
        case "00010427":
          return "Lithuanian";
        case "00000427":
          return "Lithuanian ibm";
        case "00020427":
          return "Lithuanian standard";
        case "0000046E":
          return "Luxembourgish";
        case "0000042F":
          return "Macedonian (fyrom)";
        case "0001042F":
          return "Macedonian (fyrom) - standard";
        case "0000044C":
          return "Malayalam";
        case "0000043A":
          return "Maltese 47-key";
        case "0001043A":
          return "Maltese 48-key";
        case "0000044E":
          return "Marathi";
        case "00000481":
          return "Maroi";
        case "00000450":
          return "Mongolian cyrillic";
        case "00000850":
          return "Mongolian (mongolian script)";
        case "00000461":
          return "Nepali";
        case "00000414":
          return "Norwegian";
        case "0000043B":
          return "Norwegian with sami";
        case "00000448":
          return "Oriya";
        case "00000463":
          return "Pashto (afghanistan)";
        case "00000429":
          return "Persian";
        case "00000415":
          return "Polish (programmers)";
        case "00010415":
          return "Polish (214)";
        case "00000816":
          return "Portuguese";
        case "00000416":
          return "Portuguese (brazillian abnt)";
        case "00010416":
          return "Portuguese (brazillian abnt2)";
        case "00000446":
          return "Punjabi";
        case "00010418":
          return "Romanian (standard)";
        case "00000418":
          return "Romanian (legacy)";
        case "00020418":
          return "Romanian (programmers)";
        case "00000419":
          return "Russian";
        case "00010419":
          return "Russian (typewriter)";
        case "0002083B":
          return "Sami extended finland-sweden";
        case "0001043B":
          return "Sami extended norway";
        case "00000C1A":
          return "Serbian (cyrillic)";
        case "0000081A":
          return "Serbian (latin)";
        case "0000046C":
          return "Sesotho sa Leboa";
        case "00000432":
          return "Setswana";
        case "0000045B":
          return "Sinhala";
        case "0001045B":
          return "Sinhala -Wij 9";
        case "0000041B":
          return "Slovak";
        case "0001041B":
          return "Slovak (qwerty)";
        case "00000424":
          return "Slovenian";
        case "0001042E":
          return "Sorbian extended";
        case "0002042E":
          return "Sorbian standard";
        case "0000042E":
          return "Sorbian standard (legacy)";
        case "0000040A":
          return "Spanish";
        case "0001040A":
          return "Spanish variation";
        case "0000041D":
          return "Swedish";
        case "0000083B":
          return "Swedish with sami";
        case "00000807":
          return "Swiss german";
        case "0000100C":
          return "Swiss french";
        case "0000045A":
          return "Syriac";
        case "0001045A":
          return "Syriac phonetic";
        case "00000428":
          return "Tajik";
        case "00000449":
          return "Tamil";
        case "00000444":
          return "Tatar";
        case "0000044A":
          return "Telugu";
        case "0000041E":
          return "Thai Kedmanee";
        case "0002041E":
          return "Thai Kedmanee (non-shiftlock)";
        case "0001041E":
          return "Thai Pattachote";
        case "0003041E":
          return "Thai Pattachote (non-shiftlock)";
        case "00000451":
          return "Tibetan (prc)";
        case "0001041F":
          return "Turkish F";
        case "0000041F":
          return "Turkish Q";
        case "00000442":
          return "Turkmen";
        case "00000422":
          return "Ukrainian";
        case "00020422":
          return "Ukrainian (enhanced)";
        case "00000809":
          return "United Kingdom";
        case "00000452":
          return "United Kingdom Extended";
        case "00000409":
          return "United States";
        case "00010409":
          return "United States - dvorak";
        case "00030409":
          return "United States - dvorak left hand";
        case "00050409":
          return "United States - dvorak right hand";
        case "00004009":
          return "United States - india";
        case "00020409":
          return "United States - international";
        case "00000420":
          return "Urdu";
        case "00010480":
          return "Uyghur";
        case "00000480":
          return "Uyghur (legacy)";
        case "00000843":
          return "Uzbek cyrillic";
        case "0000042A":
          return "Vietnamese";
        case "00000485":
          return "Yakut";
        case "0000046A":
          return "Yoruba";
        case "00000488":
          return "Wolof";

        default:
          return "unknown";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting KLID from HKL is a bit tricky and [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72381670/1795050).

Current layout KLID (do not confuse with LCID) may be found by a [GetKeyboardLayoutName](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardlayoutnamew) ("name" is misleading here) call. Having the KLID string, you can get localized keyboard layout name (for example "[Ukrainian (Enhanced)](https://learn.microsoft.com/globalization/keyboards/kbdur1)" string from "00020422").

To do this, according to [Create Resources for Keyboard Layout Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/intl/using-registry-string-redirection):

If your application implements a keyboard layout, it requires a localizable string resource for the name of the layout for screen display, for example, in lists of keyboard layouts. Each keyboard layout has a registry key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts`.

Among the values for that key are `Layout Text`, a human-readable name for backward compatibility, and `Layout Display Name`. The data supplied for `Layout Display Name` should be a string reference of the form `@<path>,-resID`, referring to a localizable string resource associated with the keyboard layout.

You can use [RegLoadMUIString](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regloadmuistringw) API to load a [language-neutral registry value](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/intl/locating-redirected-strings#load-a-language-neutral-registry-value) in `@<path>,-resID` format. Alternatively, you can use [SHLoadIndirectString](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shloadindirectstring) that works with already loaded strings in this format.

You can look at [System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.LayoutName](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/main/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/Input/InputLanguage.cs#L102-L110) implementation for example code with fallback string:

```cs
private const string KeyboardLayoutsRegistryPath = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts";


/// <summary>
///  Returns the name of the current keyboard layout as it appears in the Windows
///  Regional Settings on the computer.
/// </summary>
public string LayoutName
{
    get
    {
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/intl/using-registry-string-redirection#create-resources-for-keyboard-layout-strings
        using RegistryKey? key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey($@"{KeyboardLayoutsRegistryPath}\{LayoutId}");
        return key.GetMUIString("Layout Display Name", "Layout Text") ?? SR.UnknownInputLanguageLayout;
    }
}

public static string? GetMUIString(this RegistryKey? key, string keyName, string fallbackKeyName)
{
    return key is not null
        ? PInvoke.RegLoadMUIString(key, keyName, out var localizedValue)
            ? localizedValue
            : key.GetValue(fallbackKeyName) is string value
                ? value
                : null
        : null;
}

[SkipLocalsInit]
public static unsafe bool RegLoadMUIString(RegistryKey key, string keyName, out string localizedValue)
{
    using BufferScope<char> buffer = new(stackalloc char[128]);

    while (true)
    {
        fixed (char* pszOutBuf = buffer)
        {
            uint bytes = 0;
            var errorCode = RegLoadMUIString(
                (System.Registry.HKEY)key.Handle.DangerousGetHandle(),
                keyName,
                pszOutBuf,
                (uint)(buffer.Length * sizeof(char)),
                &bytes,
                0,
                null);

            // The buffer is too small. Try again with a larger buffer.
            if (errorCode == WIN32_ERROR.ERROR_MORE_DATA)
            {
                buffer.EnsureCapacity((int)(bytes / sizeof(char)));
                continue;
            }

            localizedValue = errorCode == WIN32_ERROR.ERROR_SUCCESS
                ? buffer[..Math.Max((int)(bytes / sizeof(char)) - 1, 0)].ToString()
                : string.Empty;

            return errorCode == WIN32_ERROR.ERROR_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no in-built function to do this. You may have to use the solution posted here:
[How to convert Microsoft Locale ID (LCID) into language code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192361/how-to-convert-microsoft-locale-id-lcid-into-language-code-or-locale-object-in)

Answer (score 0):

JSONinfied version of @BillTarbell 's answer:

```
{
  "0000041C": "Albanian",
  "00000401": "Arabic (101)",
  "00010401": "Arabic (102)",
  "00020401": "Arabic (102) Azerty",
  "0000042B": "Armenian eastern",
  "0001042B": "Armenian Western",
  "0000044D": "Assamese - inscript",
  "0000082C": "Azeri Cyrillic",
  "0000042C": "Azeri Latin",
  "0000046D": "Bashkir",
  "00000423": "Belarusian",
  "0000080C": "Belgian French",
  "00000813": "Belgian (period)",
  "0001080C": "Belgian (comma)",
  "00000445": "Bengali",
  "00010445": "Bengali - inscript (legacy)",
  "00020445": "Bengali - inscript",
  "0000201A": "Bosnian (cyrillic)",
  "00030402": "Bulgarian",
  "00000402": "Bulgarian(typewriter)",
  "00010402": "Bulgarian (latin)",
  "00020402": "Bulgarian (phonetic)",
  "00040402": "Bulgarian (phonetic traditional)",
  "00011009": "Canada Multilingual",
  "00001009": "Canada French",
  "00000C0C": "Canada French (legacy)",
  "00000404": "Chinese (traditional) - us keyboard",
  "00000804": "Chinese (simplified) -us keyboard",
  "00000C04": "Chinese (traditional, hong kong s.a.r.) - us keyboard",
  "00001004": "Chinese (simplified, singapore) - us keyboard",
  "00001404": "Chinese (traditional, macao s.a.r.) - us keyboard",
  "00000405": "Czech",
  "00020405": "Czech programmers",
  "00010405": "Czech (qwerty)",
  "0000041A": "Croatian",
  "00000439": "Deanagari - inscript",
  "00000406": "Danish",
  "00000465": "Divehi phonetic",
  "00010465": "Divehi typewriter",
  "00000413": "Dutch",
  "00000425": "Estonian",
  "00000438": "Faeroese",
  "0000040B": "Finnish",
  "0001083B": "Finnish with sami",
  "0000040C": "French",
  "00011809": "Gaelic",
  "00000437": "Georgian",
  "00020437": "Georgian (ergonomic)",
  "00010437": "Georgian (qwerty)",
  "00000407": "German",
  "00010407": "German (ibm)",
  "0000046F": "Greenlandic",
  "00000468": "Hausa",
  "0000040D": "Hebrew",
  "00010439": "Hindi traditional",
  "00000408": "Greek",
  "00010408": "Greek (220)",
  "00030408": "Greek (220) latin",
  "00020408": "Greek (319)",
  "00040408": "Greek (319) latin",
  "00050408": "Greek latin",
  "00060408": "Greek polyonic",
  "00000447": "Gujarati",
  "0000040E": "Hungarian",
  "0001040E": "Hungarian 101 key",
  "0000040F": "Icelandic",
  "00000470": "Igbo",
  "0000085D": "Inuktitut - latin",
  "0001045D": "Inuktitut - naqittaut",
  "00001809": "Irish",
  "00000410": "Italian",
  "00010410": "Italian (142)",
  "00000411": "Japanese",
  "0000044B": "Kannada",
  "0000043F": "Kazakh",
  "00000453": "Khmer",
  "00000412": "Korean",
  "00000440": "Kyrgyz cyrillic",
  "00000454": "Lao",
  "0000080A": "Latin america",
  "00000426": "Latvian",
  "00010426": "Latvian (qwerty)",
  "00010427": "Lithuanian",
  "00000427": "Lithuanian ibm",
  "00020427": "Lithuanian standard",
  "0000046E": "Luxembourgish",
  "0000042F": "Macedonian (fyrom)",
  "0001042F": "Macedonian (fyrom) - standard",
  "0000044C": "Malayalam",
  "0000043A": "Maltese 47-key",
  "0001043A": "Maltese 48-key",
  "0000044E": "Marathi",
  "00000481": "Maroi",
  "00000450": "Mongolian cyrillic",
  "00000850": "Mongolian (mongolian script)",
  "00000461": "Nepali",
  "00000414": "Norwegian",
  "0000043B": "Norwegian with sami",
  "00000448": "Oriya",
  "00000463": "Pashto (afghanistan)",
  "00000429": "Persian",
  "00000415": "Polish (programmers)",
  "00010415": "Polish (214)",
  "00000816": "Portuguese",
  "00000416": "Portuguese (brazillian abnt)",
  "00010416": "Portuguese (brazillian abnt2)",
  "00000446": "Punjabi",
  "00010418": "Romanian (standard)",
  "00000418": "Romanian (legacy)",
  "00020418": "Romanian (programmers)",
  "00000419": "Russian",
  "00010419": "Russian (typewriter)",
  "0002083B": "Sami extended finland-sweden",
  "0001043B": "Sami extended norway",
  "00000C1A": "Serbian (cyrillic)",
  "0000081A": "Serbian (latin)",
  "0000046C": "Sesotho sa Leboa",
  "00000432": "Setswana",
  "0000045B": "Sinhala",
  "0001045B": "Sinhala -Wij 9",
  "0000041B": "Slovak",
  "0001041B": "Slovak (qwerty)",
  "00000424": "Slovenian",
  "0001042E": "Sorbian extended",
  "0002042E": "Sorbian standard",
  "0000042E": "Sorbian standard (legacy)",
  "0000040A": "Spanish",
  "0001040A": "Spanish variation",
  "0000041D": "Swedish",
  "0000083B": "Swedish with sami",
  "00000807": "Swiss german",
  "0000100C": "Swiss french",
  "0000045A": "Syriac",
  "0001045A": "Syriac phonetic",
  "00000428": "Tajik",
  "00000449": "Tamil",
  "00000444": "Tatar",
  "0000044A": "Telugu",
  "0000041E": "Thai Kedmanee",
  "0002041E": "Thai Kedmanee (non-shiftlock)",
  "0001041E": "Thai Pattachote",
  "0003041E": "Thai Pattachote (non-shiftlock)",
  "00000451": "Tibetan (prc)",
  "0001041F": "Turkish F",
  "0000041F": "Turkish Q",
  "00000442": "Turkmen",
  "00000422": "Ukrainian",
  "00020422": "Ukrainian (enhanced)",
  "00000809": "United Kingdom",
  "00000452": "United Kingdom Extended",
  "00000409": "United States",
  "00010409": "United States - dvorak",
  "00030409": "United States - dvorak left hand",
  "00050409": "United States - dvorak right hand",
  "00004009": "United States - india",
  "00020409": "United States - international",
  "00000420": "Urdu",
  "00010480": "Uyghur",
  "00000480": "Uyghur (legacy)",
  "00000843": "Uzbek cyrillic",
  "0000042A": "Vietnamese",
  "00000485": "Yakut",
  "0000046A": "Yoruba",
  "00000488": "Wolof"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An even better way to do this is here.

There is a list of all language codes from Microsoft. [The link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oe376/6c085406-a698-4e12-9d4d-c3b0ee3dbc4a). Here is the script which you can use to parse all the values from there by yourself, if you want:

```
function getLanguages() {
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr");

    const res = {};

    let i = 0;

    for (const row of rows) {
        try {
            let [ int_code, desc, bcp_47_code ] = row.querySelectorAll("td>p");
            int_code = parseInt(int_code.textContent.trim());
            if (isNaN(int_code)) {
                throw new Error("int code is NaN");
            }
            desc = desc.textContent.trim();
            bcp_47_code = bcp_47_code.textContent.trim();
            const obj = { int_code, desc, bcp_47_code };
            res[int_code] = obj;
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(`ROW #${i} ERROR:`, err);
        } finally {
            i++;
        }
    }
    
    return res;
}
```

Just paste it into your devtools console and call the function. I will also provide the result of execution in JSON format for readers' convenience:

```
{
  "1025": {
    "int_code": 1025,
    "desc": "Arabic - Saudi Arabia",
    "bcp_47_code": "ar-SA"
  },
  "1026": {
    "int_code": 1026,
    "desc": "Bulgarian",
    "bcp_47_code": "bg-BG"
  },
  "1027": {
    "int_code": 1027,
    "desc": "Catalan",
    "bcp_47_code": "ca-ES"
  },
  "1028": {
    "int_code": 1028,
    "desc": "Chinese - Taiwan",
    "bcp_47_code": "zh-TW"
  },
  "1029": {
    "int_code": 1029,
    "desc": "Czech",
    "bcp_47_code": "cs-CZ"
  },
  "1030": {
    "int_code": 1030,
    "desc": "Danish",
    "bcp_47_code": "da-DK"
  },
  "1031": {
    "int_code": 1031,
    "desc": "German - Germany",
    "bcp_47_code": "de-DE"
  },
  "1032": {
    "int_code": 1032,
    "desc": "Greek",
    "bcp_47_code": "el-GR"
  },
  "1033": {
    "int_code": 1033,
    "desc": "English - United States",
    "bcp_47_code": "en-US"
  },
  "1034": {
    "int_code": 1034,
    "desc": "Spanish - Spain (Traditional Sort)",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-ES"
  },
  "1035": {
    "int_code": 1035,
    "desc": "Finnish",
    "bcp_47_code": "fi-FI"
  },
  "1036": {
    "int_code": 1036,
    "desc": "French - France",
    "bcp_47_code": "fr-FR"
  },
  "1037": {
    "int_code": 1037,
    "desc": "Hebrew",
    "bcp_47_code": "he-IL"
  },
  "1038": {
    "int_code": 1038,
    "desc": "Hungarian",
    "bcp_47_code": "hu-HU"
  },
  "1039": {
    "int_code": 1039,
    "desc": "Icelandic",
    "bcp_47_code": "is-IS"
  },
  "1040": {
    "int_code": 1040,
    "desc": "Italian - Italy",
    "bcp_47_code": "it-IT"
  },
  "1041": {
    "int_code": 1041,
    "desc": "Japanese",
    "bcp_47_code": "ja-JP"
  },
  "1042": {
    "int_code": 1042,
    "desc": "Korean",
    "bcp_47_code": "ko-KR"
  },
  "1043": {
    "int_code": 1043,
    "desc": "Dutch - Netherlands",
    "bcp_47_code": "nl-NL"
  },
  "1044": {
    "int_code": 1044,
    "desc": "Norwegian (Bokmål)",
    "bcp_47_code": "nb-NO"
  },
  "1045": {
    "int_code": 1045,
    "desc": "Polish",
    "bcp_47_code": "pl-PL"
  },
  "1046": {
    "int_code": 1046,
    "desc": "Portuguese - Brazil",
    "bcp_47_code": "pt-BR"
  },
  "1047": {
    "int_code": 1047,
    "desc": "Rhaeto-Romanic",
    "bcp_47_code": "rm-CH"
  },
  "1048": {
    "int_code": 1048,
    "desc": "Romanian",
    "bcp_47_code": "ro-RO"
  },
  "1049": {
    "int_code": 1049,
    "desc": "Russian",
    "bcp_47_code": "ru-RU"
  },
  "1050": {
    "int_code": 1050,
    "desc": "Croatian",
    "bcp_47_code": "hr-HR"
  },
  "1051": {
    "int_code": 1051,
    "desc": "Slovak",
    "bcp_47_code": "sk-SK"
  },
  "1052": {
    "int_code": 1052,
    "desc": "Albanian - Albania",
    "bcp_47_code": "sq-AL"
  },
  "1053": {
    "int_code": 1053,
    "desc": "Swedish",
    "bcp_47_code": "sv-SE"
  },
  "1054": {
    "int_code": 1054,
    "desc": "Thai",
    "bcp_47_code": "th-TH"
  },
  "1055": {
    "int_code": 1055,
    "desc": "Turkish",
    "bcp_47_code": "tr-TR"
  },
  "1056": {
    "int_code": 1056,
    "desc": "Urdu - Pakistan",
    "bcp_47_code": "ur-PK"
  },
  "1057": {
    "int_code": 1057,
    "desc": "Indonesian",
    "bcp_47_code": "id-ID"
  },
  "1058": {
    "int_code": 1058,
    "desc": "Ukrainian",
    "bcp_47_code": "uk-UA"
  },
  "1059": {
    "int_code": 1059,
    "desc": "Belarusian",
    "bcp_47_code": "be-BY"
  },
  "1060": {
    "int_code": 1060,
    "desc": "Slovenian",
    "bcp_47_code": "sl-SI"
  },
  "1061": {
    "int_code": 1061,
    "desc": "Estonian",
    "bcp_47_code": "et-EE"
  },
  "1062": {
    "int_code": 1062,
    "desc": "Latvian",
    "bcp_47_code": "lv-LV"
  },
  "1063": {
    "int_code": 1063,
    "desc": "Lithuanian",
    "bcp_47_code": "lt-LT"
  },
  "1064": {
    "int_code": 1064,
    "desc": "Tajik",
    "bcp_47_code": "tg-Cyrl-TJ"
  },
  "1065": {
    "int_code": 1065,
    "desc": "Persian",
    "bcp_47_code": "fa-IR"
  },
  "1066": {
    "int_code": 1066,
    "desc": "Vietnamese",
    "bcp_47_code": "vi-VN"
  },
  "1067": {
    "int_code": 1067,
    "desc": "Armenian - Armenia",
    "bcp_47_code": "hy-AM"
  },
  "1068": {
    "int_code": 1068,
    "desc": "Azeri (Latin)",
    "bcp_47_code": "az-Latn-AZ"
  },
  "1069": {
    "int_code": 1069,
    "desc": "Basque",
    "bcp_47_code": "eu-ES"
  },
  "1070": {
    "int_code": 1070,
    "desc": "Sorbian",
    "bcp_47_code": "wen-DE"
  },
  "1071": {
    "int_code": 1071,
    "desc": "F.Y.R.O. Macedonian",
    "bcp_47_code": "mk-MK"
  },
  "1072": {
    "int_code": 1072,
    "desc": "Sutu",
    "bcp_47_code": "st-ZA"
  },
  "1073": {
    "int_code": 1073,
    "desc": "Tsonga",
    "bcp_47_code": "ts-ZA"
  },
  "1074": {
    "int_code": 1074,
    "desc": "Tswana",
    "bcp_47_code": "tn-ZA"
  },
  "1075": {
    "int_code": 1075,
    "desc": "Venda",
    "bcp_47_code": "ven-ZA"
  },
  "1076": {
    "int_code": 1076,
    "desc": "Xhosa",
    "bcp_47_code": "xh-ZA"
  },
  "1077": {
    "int_code": 1077,
    "desc": "Zulu",
    "bcp_47_code": "zu-ZA"
  },
  "1078": {
    "int_code": 1078,
    "desc": "Afrikaans - South Africa",
    "bcp_47_code": "af-ZA"
  },
  "1079": {
    "int_code": 1079,
    "desc": "Georgian",
    "bcp_47_code": "ka-GE"
  },
  "1080": {
    "int_code": 1080,
    "desc": "Faroese",
    "bcp_47_code": "fo-FO"
  },
  "1081": {
    "int_code": 1081,
    "desc": "Hindi",
    "bcp_47_code": "hi-IN"
  },
  "1082": {
    "int_code": 1082,
    "desc": "Maltese",
    "bcp_47_code": "mt-MT"
  },
  "1083": {
    "int_code": 1083,
    "desc": "Sami",
    "bcp_47_code": "se-NO"
  },
  "1084": {
    "int_code": 1084,
    "desc": "Gaelic (Scotland)",
    "bcp_47_code": "gd-GB"
  },
  "1085": {
    "int_code": 1085,
    "desc": "Yiddish",
    "bcp_47_code": "yi"
  },
  "1086": {
    "int_code": 1086,
    "desc": "Malay - Malaysia",
    "bcp_47_code": "ms-MY"
  },
  "1087": {
    "int_code": 1087,
    "desc": "Kazakh",
    "bcp_47_code": "kk-KZ"
  },
  "1088": {
    "int_code": 1088,
    "desc": "Kyrgyz (Cyrillic)",
    "bcp_47_code": "ky-KG"
  },
  "1089": {
    "int_code": 1089,
    "desc": "Swahili",
    "bcp_47_code": "sw-KE"
  },
  "1090": {
    "int_code": 1090,
    "desc": "Turkmen",
    "bcp_47_code": "tk-TM"
  },
  "1091": {
    "int_code": 1091,
    "desc": "Uzbek (Latin)",
    "bcp_47_code": "uz-Latn-UZ"
  },
  "1092": {
    "int_code": 1092,
    "desc": "Tatar",
    "bcp_47_code": "tt-RU"
  },
  "1093": {
    "int_code": 1093,
    "desc": "Bengali (India)",
    "bcp_47_code": "bn-IN"
  },
  "1094": {
    "int_code": 1094,
    "desc": "Punjabi",
    "bcp_47_code": "pa-IN"
  },
  "1095": {
    "int_code": 1095,
    "desc": "Gujarati",
    "bcp_47_code": "gu-IN"
  },
  "1096": {
    "int_code": 1096,
    "desc": "Oriya",
    "bcp_47_code": "or-IN"
  },
  "1097": {
    "int_code": 1097,
    "desc": "Tamil",
    "bcp_47_code": "ta-IN"
  },
  "1098": {
    "int_code": 1098,
    "desc": "Telugu",
    "bcp_47_code": "te-IN"
  },
  "1099": {
    "int_code": 1099,
    "desc": "Kannada",
    "bcp_47_code": "kn-IN"
  },
  "1100": {
    "int_code": 1100,
    "desc": "Malayalam",
    "bcp_47_code": "ml-IN"
  },
  "1101": {
    "int_code": 1101,
    "desc": "Assamese",
    "bcp_47_code": "as-IN"
  },
  "1102": {
    "int_code": 1102,
    "desc": "Marathi",
    "bcp_47_code": "mr-IN"
  },
  "1103": {
    "int_code": 1103,
    "desc": "Sanskrit",
    "bcp_47_code": "sa-IN"
  },
  "1104": {
    "int_code": 1104,
    "desc": "Mongolian (Cyrillic)",
    "bcp_47_code": "mn-MN"
  },
  "1105": {
    "int_code": 1105,
    "desc": "Tibetan - People's Republic of China",
    "bcp_47_code": "bo-CN"
  },
  "1106": {
    "int_code": 1106,
    "desc": "Welsh",
    "bcp_47_code": "cy-GB"
  },
  "1107": {
    "int_code": 1107,
    "desc": "Khmer",
    "bcp_47_code": "km-KH"
  },
  "1108": {
    "int_code": 1108,
    "desc": "Lao",
    "bcp_47_code": "lo-LA"
  },
  "1109": {
    "int_code": 1109,
    "desc": "Burmese",
    "bcp_47_code": "my-MM"
  },
  "1110": {
    "int_code": 1110,
    "desc": "Galician",
    "bcp_47_code": "gl-ES"
  },
  "1111": {
    "int_code": 1111,
    "desc": "Konkani",
    "bcp_47_code": "kok-IN"
  },
  "1112": {
    "int_code": 1112,
    "desc": "Manipuri",
    "bcp_47_code": "mni"
  },
  "1113": {
    "int_code": 1113,
    "desc": "Sindhi - India",
    "bcp_47_code": "sd-IN"
  },
  "1114": {
    "int_code": 1114,
    "desc": "Syriac",
    "bcp_47_code": "syr-SY"
  },
  "1115": {
    "int_code": 1115,
    "desc": "Sinhalese - Sri Lanka",
    "bcp_47_code": "si-LK"
  },
  "1116": {
    "int_code": 1116,
    "desc": "Cherokee - United States",
    "bcp_47_code": "chr-US"
  },
  "1117": {
    "int_code": 1117,
    "desc": "Inuktitut",
    "bcp_47_code": "iu-Cans-CA"
  },
  "1118": {
    "int_code": 1118,
    "desc": "Amharic - Ethiopia",
    "bcp_47_code": "am-ET"
  },
  "1119": {
    "int_code": 1119,
    "desc": "Tamazight (Arabic)",
    "bcp_47_code": "tmz"
  },
  "1120": {
    "int_code": 1120,
    "desc": "Kashmiri (Arabic)",
    "bcp_47_code": "ks-Arab-IN"
  },
  "1121": {
    "int_code": 1121,
    "desc": "Nepali",
    "bcp_47_code": "ne-NP"
  },
  "1122": {
    "int_code": 1122,
    "desc": "Frisian - Netherlands",
    "bcp_47_code": "fy-NL"
  },
  "1123": {
    "int_code": 1123,
    "desc": "Pashto",
    "bcp_47_code": "ps-AF"
  },
  "1124": {
    "int_code": 1124,
    "desc": "Filipino",
    "bcp_47_code": "fil-PH"
  },
  "1125": {
    "int_code": 1125,
    "desc": "Divehi",
    "bcp_47_code": "dv-MV"
  },
  "1126": {
    "int_code": 1126,
    "desc": "Edo",
    "bcp_47_code": "bin-NG"
  },
  "1127": {
    "int_code": 1127,
    "desc": "Fulfulde - Nigeria",
    "bcp_47_code": "fuv-NG"
  },
  "1128": {
    "int_code": 1128,
    "desc": "Hausa - Nigeria",
    "bcp_47_code": "ha-Latn-NG"
  },
  "1129": {
    "int_code": 1129,
    "desc": "Ibibio - Nigeria",
    "bcp_47_code": "ibb-NG"
  },
  "1130": {
    "int_code": 1130,
    "desc": "Yoruba",
    "bcp_47_code": "yo-NG"
  },
  "1131": {
    "int_code": 1131,
    "desc": "Quecha - Bolivia",
    "bcp_47_code": "quz-BO"
  },
  "1132": {
    "int_code": 1132,
    "desc": "Sepedi",
    "bcp_47_code": "nso-ZA"
  },
  "1136": {
    "int_code": 1136,
    "desc": "Igbo - Nigeria",
    "bcp_47_code": "ig-NG"
  },
  "1137": {
    "int_code": 1137,
    "desc": "Kanuri - Nigeria",
    "bcp_47_code": "kr-NG"
  },
  "1138": {
    "int_code": 1138,
    "desc": "Oromo",
    "bcp_47_code": "gaz-ET"
  },
  "1139": {
    "int_code": 1139,
    "desc": "Tigrigna - Ethiopia",
    "bcp_47_code": "ti-ER"
  },
  "1140": {
    "int_code": 1140,
    "desc": "Guarani - Paraguay",
    "bcp_47_code": "gn-PY"
  },
  "1141": {
    "int_code": 1141,
    "desc": "Hawaiian - United States",
    "bcp_47_code": "haw-US"
  },
  "1142": {
    "int_code": 1142,
    "desc": "Latin",
    "bcp_47_code": "la"
  },
  "1143": {
    "int_code": 1143,
    "desc": "Somali",
    "bcp_47_code": "so-SO"
  },
  "1144": {
    "int_code": 1144,
    "desc": "Yi",
    "bcp_47_code": "ii-CN"
  },
  "1145": {
    "int_code": 1145,
    "desc": "Papiamentu",
    "bcp_47_code": "pap-AN"
  },
  "1152": {
    "int_code": 1152,
    "desc": "Uighur - China",
    "bcp_47_code": "ug-Arab-CN"
  },
  "1153": {
    "int_code": 1153,
    "desc": "Maori - New Zealand",
    "bcp_47_code": "mi-NZ"
  },
  "2049": {
    "int_code": 2049,
    "desc": "Arabic - Iraq",
    "bcp_47_code": "ar-IQ"
  },
  "2052": {
    "int_code": 2052,
    "desc": "Chinese - People's Republic of China",
    "bcp_47_code": "zh-CN"
  },
  "2055": {
    "int_code": 2055,
    "desc": "German - Switzerland",
    "bcp_47_code": "de-CH"
  },
  "2057": {
    "int_code": 2057,
    "desc": "English - United Kingdom",
    "bcp_47_code": "en-GB"
  },
  "2058": {
    "int_code": 2058,
    "desc": "Spanish - Mexico",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-MX"
  },
  "2060": {
    "int_code": 2060,
    "desc": "French - Belgium",
    "bcp_47_code": "fr-BE"
  },
  "2064": {
    "int_code": 2064,
    "desc": "Italian - Switzerland",
    "bcp_47_code": "it-CH"
  },
  "2067": {
    "int_code": 2067,
    "desc": "Dutch - Belgium",
    "bcp_47_code": "nl-BE"
  },
  "2068": {
    "int_code": 2068,
    "desc": "Norwegian (Nynorsk)",
    "bcp_47_code": "nn-NO"
  },
  "2070": {
    "int_code": 2070,
    "desc": "Portuguese - Portugal",
    "bcp_47_code": "pt-PT"
  },
  "2072": {
    "int_code": 2072,
    "desc": "Romanian - Moldava",
    "bcp_47_code": "ro-MD"
  },
  "2073": {
    "int_code": 2073,
    "desc": "Russian - Moldava",
    "bcp_47_code": "ru-MD"
  },
  "2074": {
    "int_code": 2074,
    "desc": "Serbian (Latin)",
    "bcp_47_code": "sr-Latn-CS"
  },
  "2077": {
    "int_code": 2077,
    "desc": "Swedish - Finland",
    "bcp_47_code": "sv-FI"
  },
  "2080": {
    "int_code": 2080,
    "desc": "Urdu - India",
    "bcp_47_code": "ur-IN"
  },
  "2092": {
    "int_code": 2092,
    "desc": "Azeri (Cyrillic)",
    "bcp_47_code": "az-Cyrl-AZ"
  },
  "2108": {
    "int_code": 2108,
    "desc": "Gaelic (Ireland)",
    "bcp_47_code": "ga-IE"
  },
  "2110": {
    "int_code": 2110,
    "desc": "Malay - Brunei Darussalam",
    "bcp_47_code": "ms-BN"
  },
  "2115": {
    "int_code": 2115,
    "desc": "Uzbek (Cyrillic)",
    "bcp_47_code": "uz-Cyrl-UZ"
  },
  "2117": {
    "int_code": 2117,
    "desc": "Bengali (Bangladesh)",
    "bcp_47_code": "bn-BD"
  },
  "2118": {
    "int_code": 2118,
    "desc": "Punjabi (Pakistan)",
    "bcp_47_code": "pa-PK"
  },
  "2128": {
    "int_code": 2128,
    "desc": "Mongolian (Mongolian)",
    "bcp_47_code": "mn-Mong-CN"
  },
  "2129": {
    "int_code": 2129,
    "desc": "Tibetan - Bhutan",
    "bcp_47_code": "bo-BT"
  },
  "2137": {
    "int_code": 2137,
    "desc": "Sindhi - Pakistan",
    "bcp_47_code": "sd-PK"
  },
  "2143": {
    "int_code": 2143,
    "desc": "Tamazight (Latin)",
    "bcp_47_code": "tzm-Latn-DZ"
  },
  "2144": {
    "int_code": 2144,
    "desc": "Kashmiri (Devanagari)",
    "bcp_47_code": "ks-Deva-IN"
  },
  "2145": {
    "int_code": 2145,
    "desc": "Nepali - India",
    "bcp_47_code": "ne-IN"
  },
  "2155": {
    "int_code": 2155,
    "desc": "Quecha - Ecuador",
    "bcp_47_code": "quz-EC"
  },
  "2163": {
    "int_code": 2163,
    "desc": "Tigrigna - Eritrea",
    "bcp_47_code": "ti-ET"
  },
  "3073": {
    "int_code": 3073,
    "desc": "Arabic - Egypt",
    "bcp_47_code": "ar-EG"
  },
  "3076": {
    "int_code": 3076,
    "desc": "Chinese - Hong Kong SAR",
    "bcp_47_code": "zh-HK"
  },
  "3079": {
    "int_code": 3079,
    "desc": "German - Austria",
    "bcp_47_code": "de-AT"
  },
  "3081": {
    "int_code": 3081,
    "desc": "English - Australia",
    "bcp_47_code": "en-AU"
  },
  "3082": {
    "int_code": 3082,
    "desc": "Spanish - Spain (Modern Sort)",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-ES"
  },
  "3084": {
    "int_code": 3084,
    "desc": "French - Canada",
    "bcp_47_code": "fr-CA"
  },
  "3098": {
    "int_code": 3098,
    "desc": "Serbian (Cyrillic)",
    "bcp_47_code": "sr-Cyrl-CS"
  },
  "3179": {
    "int_code": 3179,
    "desc": "Quecha - Peru",
    "bcp_47_code": "quz-PE"
  },
  "4097": {
    "int_code": 4097,
    "desc": "Arabic - Libya",
    "bcp_47_code": "ar-LY"
  },
  "4100": {
    "int_code": 4100,
    "desc": "Chinese - Singapore",
    "bcp_47_code": "zh-SG"
  },
  "4103": {
    "int_code": 4103,
    "desc": "German - Luxembourg",
    "bcp_47_code": "de-LU"
  },
  "4105": {
    "int_code": 4105,
    "desc": "English - Canada",
    "bcp_47_code": "en-CA"
  },
  "4106": {
    "int_code": 4106,
    "desc": "Spanish - Guatemala",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-GT"
  },
  "4108": {
    "int_code": 4108,
    "desc": "French - Switzerland",
    "bcp_47_code": "fr-CH"
  },
  "4122": {
    "int_code": 4122,
    "desc": "Croatian (Bosnia/Herzegovina)",
    "bcp_47_code": "hr-BA"
  },
  "5121": {
    "int_code": 5121,
    "desc": "Arabic - Algeria",
    "bcp_47_code": "ar-DZ"
  },
  "5124": {
    "int_code": 5124,
    "desc": "Chinese - Macao SAR",
    "bcp_47_code": "zh-MO"
  },
  "5127": {
    "int_code": 5127,
    "desc": "German - Liechtenstein",
    "bcp_47_code": "de-LI"
  },
  "5129": {
    "int_code": 5129,
    "desc": "English - New Zealand",
    "bcp_47_code": "en-NZ"
  },
  "5130": {
    "int_code": 5130,
    "desc": "Spanish - Costa Rica",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-CR"
  },
  "5132": {
    "int_code": 5132,
    "desc": "French - Luxembourg",
    "bcp_47_code": "fr-LU"
  },
  "5146": {
    "int_code": 5146,
    "desc": "Bosnian (Bosnia/Herzegovina)",
    "bcp_47_code": "bs-Latn-BA"
  },
  "6145": {
    "int_code": 6145,
    "desc": "Arabic - Morocco",
    "bcp_47_code": "ar-MO"
  },
  "6153": {
    "int_code": 6153,
    "desc": "English - Ireland",
    "bcp_47_code": "en-IE"
  },
  "6154": {
    "int_code": 6154,
    "desc": "Spanish - Panama",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-PA"
  },
  "6156": {
    "int_code": 6156,
    "desc": "French - Monaco",
    "bcp_47_code": "fr-MC"
  },
  "7169": {
    "int_code": 7169,
    "desc": "Arabic - Tunisia",
    "bcp_47_code": "ar-TN"
  },
  "7177": {
    "int_code": 7177,
    "desc": "English - South Africa",
    "bcp_47_code": "en-ZA"
  },
  "7178": {
    "int_code": 7178,
    "desc": "Spanish - Dominican Republic",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-DO"
  },
  "7180": {
    "int_code": 7180,
    "desc": "French - West Indies",
    "bcp_47_code": "fr-029"
  },
  "8193": {
    "int_code": 8193,
    "desc": "Arabic - Oman",
    "bcp_47_code": "ar-OM"
  },
  "8201": {
    "int_code": 8201,
    "desc": "English - Jamaica",
    "bcp_47_code": "en-JM"
  },
  "8202": {
    "int_code": 8202,
    "desc": "Spanish - Venezuela",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-VE"
  },
  "8204": {
    "int_code": 8204,
    "desc": "French - Reunion",
    "bcp_47_code": "fr-RE"
  },
  "9217": {
    "int_code": 9217,
    "desc": "Arabic - Yemen",
    "bcp_47_code": "ar-YE"
  },
  "9225": {
    "int_code": 9225,
    "desc": "English - Caribbean",
    "bcp_47_code": "en-029"
  },
  "9226": {
    "int_code": 9226,
    "desc": "Spanish - Colombia",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-CO"
  },
  "9228": {
    "int_code": 9228,
    "desc": "French - Democratic Rep. of Congo",
    "bcp_47_code": "fr-CG"
  },
  "10241": {
    "int_code": 10241,
    "desc": "Arabic - Syria",
    "bcp_47_code": "ar-SY"
  },
  "10249": {
    "int_code": 10249,
    "desc": "English - Belize",
    "bcp_47_code": "en-BZ"
  },
  "10250": {
    "int_code": 10250,
    "desc": "Spanish - Peru",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-PE"
  },
  "10252": {
    "int_code": 10252,
    "desc": "French - Senegal",
    "bcp_47_code": "fr-SN"
  },
  "11265": {
    "int_code": 11265,
    "desc": "Arabic - Jordan",
    "bcp_47_code": "ar-JO"
  },
  "11273": {
    "int_code": 11273,
    "desc": "English - Trinidad",
    "bcp_47_code": "en-TT"
  },
  "11274": {
    "int_code": 11274,
    "desc": "Spanish - Argentina",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-AR"
  },
  "11276": {
    "int_code": 11276,
    "desc": "French - Cameroon",
    "bcp_47_code": "fr-CM"
  },
  "12289": {
    "int_code": 12289,
    "desc": "Arabic - Lebanon",
    "bcp_47_code": "ar-LB"
  },
  "12297": {
    "int_code": 12297,
    "desc": "English - Zimbabwe",
    "bcp_47_code": "en-ZW"
  },
  "12298": {
    "int_code": 12298,
    "desc": "Spanish - Ecuador",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-EC"
  },
  "12300": {
    "int_code": 12300,
    "desc": "French - Cote d'Ivoire",
    "bcp_47_code": "fr-CI"
  },
  "13313": {
    "int_code": 13313,
    "desc": "Arabic - Kuwait",
    "bcp_47_code": "ar-KW"
  },
  "13321": {
    "int_code": 13321,
    "desc": "English - Philippines",
    "bcp_47_code": "en-PH"
  },
  "13322": {
    "int_code": 13322,
    "desc": "Spanish - Chile",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-CL"
  },
  "13324": {
    "int_code": 13324,
    "desc": "French - Mali",
    "bcp_47_code": "fr-ML"
  },
  "14337": {
    "int_code": 14337,
    "desc": "Arabic - U.A.E.",
    "bcp_47_code": "ar-AE"
  },
  "14345": {
    "int_code": 14345,
    "desc": "English - Indonesia",
    "bcp_47_code": "en-ID"
  },
  "14346": {
    "int_code": 14346,
    "desc": "Spanish - Uruguay",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-UY"
  },
  "14348": {
    "int_code": 14348,
    "desc": "French - Morocco",
    "bcp_47_code": "fr-MA"
  },
  "15361": {
    "int_code": 15361,
    "desc": "Arabic - Bahrain",
    "bcp_47_code": "ar-BH"
  },
  "15369": {
    "int_code": 15369,
    "desc": "English - Hong Kong SAR",
    "bcp_47_code": "en-HK"
  },
  "15370": {
    "int_code": 15370,
    "desc": "Spanish - Paraguay",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-PY"
  },
  "15372": {
    "int_code": 15372,
    "desc": "French - Haiti",
    "bcp_47_code": "fr-HT"
  },
  "16385": {
    "int_code": 16385,
    "desc": "Arabic - Qatar",
    "bcp_47_code": "ar-QA"
  },
  "16393": {
    "int_code": 16393,
    "desc": "English - India",
    "bcp_47_code": "en-IN"
  },
  "16394": {
    "int_code": 16394,
    "desc": "Spanish - Bolivia",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-BO"
  },
  "17417": {
    "int_code": 17417,
    "desc": "English - Malaysia",
    "bcp_47_code": "en-MY"
  },
  "17418": {
    "int_code": 17418,
    "desc": "Spanish - El Salvador",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-SV"
  },
  "18441": {
    "int_code": 18441,
    "desc": "English - Singapore",
    "bcp_47_code": "en-SG"
  },
  "18442": {
    "int_code": 18442,
    "desc": "Spanish - Honduras",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-HN"
  },
  "19466": {
    "int_code": 19466,
    "desc": "Spanish - Nicaragua",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-NI"
  },
  "20490": {
    "int_code": 20490,
    "desc": "Spanish - Puerto Rico",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-PR"
  },
  "21514": {
    "int_code": 21514,
    "desc": "Spanish - United States",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-US"
  },
  "58378": {
    "int_code": 58378,
    "desc": "Spanish - Latin America",
    "bcp_47_code": "es-419"
  },
  "58380": {
    "int_code": 58380,
    "desc": "French - North Africa",
    "bcp_47_code": "fr-015"
  }
}
```

Next, you should call the `GetKeyboardLayoutName()` function, which will return a hexadecimal number like this: "00000423". The keys in our dictionary are integer, so you should convert it into decimal (just the plain old regular integer). I don't know how you do it in C#, but in python it is: `i = int("<hex number goes here>", 16)`.

And then you simply query our dictionary by the key we've calculated and get the full information, including description and BCP 47 code.

*Note*: the keys are `string`, because JSON doesn't support integer keys.