# How to create a list of Keyboards. Extract KLID from HKL?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, keyboard, windows-10

Windows 10 / C++ / Win32

I need to make a list of 'installed' Keyboards.

The components of my 'list' needs to contain:

- The HKL for the keyboard.
- The KLID for the keyboard.
- The values of the registry values obtained from:
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts`
- Example: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\00000409`
- Value: Layout File
- Value: Layout Text

The only way I am aware of enumerating Keyboards is via `GetKeyboardLayoutList()`, which returns a list of HKL's.

Methodology which works for 'standard' keyboards (HKL's 04090409, 04070407,..).

```cpp
TCHAR Buffer[50];
TCHAR Buffer2[50];
HKL LoadedKeyboardLayout;

// Hkl: 04090409
_stprintf_s(Buffer, (sizeof(Buffer)/sizeof(TCHAR)), _T("%08X"), (((UINT)Hkl >> 16) & 0xFFFF));
// Buffer: "0000409"
LoadedKeyboardLayout = LoadKeyboardLayout(Buffer, (UINT)0);
// It Loads

ActivateKeyboardLayout(LoadedKeyboardLayout, KLF_SETFORPROCESS);
// It Activates

GetKeyboardLayoutName(Buffer2); 
// Buffer2: "00000409"

// I can now fish the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\00000409
```

This DOES not work when the 'device identifier' is NOT 0000.

From `LoadKeyboardLayout()` documentation:

> The name of the input locale identifier to load. This name is a string composed of the hexadecimal value of the Language Identifier (low word) and a device identifier (high word). For example, U.S. English has a language identifier of 0x0409, so the primary U.S. English layout is named "00000409". Variants of U.S. English layout (such as the Dvorak layout) are named "00010409", "00020409", and so on.

If one creates a 'Custom' keyboard, I find it is impossible to get the 'device identifier' from the custom keyboards HKL.

For instance:

- Create a Custom Keyboard US with MKLCS.
- Install it.
- The 'KLID' will be 'A0000409'.
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\a0000409`
- The HKL will be 0xF0C00409 (as returned within the HKL list generated by `GetKeyboardLayoutList()`).
- In order to load the keyboard with `LoadKeyboardLayout()`, one needs 'A0000409'.
- It does not seem possible to create A0000409 from F0C00409.
- I also created my own keyboard layout without MKLCS.
- I arbitrarily named it 00060409.
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\00060409`
- It's HKL is FFFE0409 (as returned within the HKL list generated by `GetKeyboardLayoutList()`).
- It does not seem possible to create 00060409 from FFFE0409.

With all of that said, how does one obtain a KLID from an HKL?

Or, is there another way I can go about creating my list of installed keyboards?

//================================================================
11/25/2020 Addition.

Thank you Rita.

It seems as if `GetKeyboardLayoutList()` creates a list of 'Loaded' keyboard layouts.

- System loaded keyboard layouts, 0x0409409,....
- Keyboard Layouts installed via MKLCS installation.

It seems that any Keyboards defined within the following registry keys will get loaded at boot.

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout`
  Note the Preload and Substitute value's.

(Note there are many other 'Keyboard Layout' keys spread around within the registry, so I am
not sure if `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout` is the actual registry key that defines the
PreLoad - Substitutes.

- `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout`
- `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18` (My User Account)
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Keyboard Layout`
  )

So there is no doubt in my mind that Rita's example works due to the fact that her `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard` Layout contains the following entries:
Preload:
1   d0010804

Substitutes:
d0010804    a0000804

The entries may have been put there by the MKLCS installer?
Or perhaps the action of adding the keyboard via Settings->Time & Language->Click on Preferred Language->Options->Add a Keyboard

From `ActivateKeyboardLayout()` documentation:

> The input locale identifier must have been loaded by a previous call to the LoadKeyboardLayout function.

Since a0000804 (HKL: F0C00804) is actually already loaded `ActivateKeyboardLayout()` works.

Since my KLID: 00060409 is not referenced within any of the  X\Keyboard Layout Preload and Substitutes
I must physically call `LoadKeyBoardLayout(L"00060409")` in order for it to appear within the `GetKeyboardList()` HKL's.

Thanks again Rita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does one obtain a KLID from an HKL?

There seems no direct method out of box to achieve it.

A workaround is retrieving a list of HKLs, then active a layout via a `HKL`, then get its `KLID`. The following is an example:

```
int cnt = GetKeyboardLayoutList(sizeof(hklArr)/sizeof(hklArr[0]), hklArr);
if(cnt > 0)
{
    printf("keyboard list: \n");
    for (UINT i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {
        printf("%x\n", (LONG_PTR)hklArr[i]);
        if (ActivateKeyboardLayout(hklArr[i], KLF_SETFORPROCESS))
        {
            WCHAR pName[KL_NAMELENGTH];
            if (GetKeyboardLayoutName(pName))
            {
                wprintf(L"layout name (KLID): %s\n", pName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result like this:

[image]

Update:

[image]

**Update 2**: Share my creating and installing steps.

I use Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4.

1. Load an existing keyboard for testing purpose. (You can modify based on it or create your own completely.)

[image]

2. Valid and test keyboard to make sure it works as you expected. Then build DLL and setup package.

[image]

3. Run setup.exe generated by step 2. After installation complete you will see the related preload keyboard layout item in registry.

[image]

Comment: @RSullivan It seems you have some concern about this issue. I'll show my Preload list in update part of my answer. You can see that there are values related to language identifiers like: 0x0804, 0x0408 and 0409, with high word all zero.

Comment: @RSullivan After create the custom keyboard layout I install it. Then a registry key will be added to preload list: 0x00000408 for a0000408 (Greek Polytonic - Custom).

Comment: Thanks Rita. When and how is the keyboard added to the Preload list? Did the installer do it? Also please see [MSKLC / Custom.dll Source Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/170961/msklc-customdll-source-code.html)

Comment: Perhaps I am also wrong about the Preload / Substitute list? I do not see a0000804 in your Preload list. Did you un-install it?

Comment: @RSullivan The installer is the one could do registry stuff. I didn't uninstall. As I mentioned in my last comments, a0000804 will appears at: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts` while 0x00000804 appears at: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload`. I'll share my steps of creating and installing in my answer as update2 you can follow to see if it make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no safe way to do this since [it is not documented and can be changed after Windows updates](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2004/12/05/275231.html).

Proper algorithm is posted [here](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/4345).

Here is my code that is working on my Windows 10 Version 21H2 (November 2021 Update) so far:

```cpp
std::string GetKlidFromHkl(HKL hkl)
{
    wchar_t klid[KL_NAMELENGTH] = { 0 };

    WORD device = HIWORD(hkl);

    if ((device & 0xf000) == 0xf000) // `Device Handle` contains `Layout ID`
    {
        WORD layoutId = device & 0x0fff;

        HKEY key;
        CHECK_EQ(::RegOpenKeyW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Keyboard Layouts", &key), ERROR_SUCCESS);

        DWORD index = 0;
        wchar_t buffer[KL_NAMELENGTH];
        DWORD len = (DWORD)std::size(buffer);
        while (::RegEnumKeyExW(key, index, buffer, &len, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            wchar_t layoutIdBuffer[MAX_PATH] = {};
            DWORD layoutIdBufferSize = sizeof(layoutIdBuffer);
            if (::RegGetValueW(key, buffer, L"Layout Id", RRF_RT_REG_SZ, nullptr, layoutIdBuffer, &layoutIdBufferSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                if (layoutId == std::stoul(layoutIdBuffer, nullptr, 16))
                {
                    _wcsupr(buffer);
                    wcscpy(klid, buffer);
                    //DBGPRINT("Found KLID %ls by layoutId=0x%04x", klid, layoutId);
                    break;
                }
            }
            len = (DWORD)std::size(buffer);
            ++index;
        }

        CHECK_EQ(::RegCloseKey(key), ERROR_SUCCESS);
    }
    else
    {
        // Use input language only if keyboard layout language is not available. This
        // is crucial in cases when keyboard is installed more than once or under
        // different languages. For example when French keyboard is installed under US
        // input language we need to return French keyboard identifier.
        if (device == 0)
        {
            device = LOWORD(hkl);
        }

        std::swprintf(klid, std::size(klid), L"%08X", device);
        //DBGPRINT("Found KLID %ls by langId=0x%04x", klid, device);
    }

    return utf8::narrow(klid);
}
```

Also you can use this code to enumerate layout profiles with KLID in `LAYOUTORTIPPROFILE.szId`:

```
typedef struct tagLAYOUTORTIPPROFILE {
    DWORD dwProfileType;
    LANGID langid;
    CLSID clsid;
    GUID guidProfile;
    GUID catid;
    DWORD dwSubstituteLayout;
    DWORD dwFlags;
    WCHAR szId[MAX_PATH];
} LAYOUTORTIPPROFILE;

// Flags used in LAYOUTORTIPPROFILE::dwProfileType
#define LOTP_INPUTPROCESSOR 1
#define LOTP_KEYBOARDLAYOUT 2

// Flags used in LAYOUTORTIPPROFILE::dwFlags.
#define LOT_DEFAULT 0x0001
#define LOT_DISABLED 0x0002

std::vector<LAYOUTORTIPPROFILE> EnumLayoutProfiles()
{
    // http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2008/09/29/8968315.html
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tsf/enumenabledlayoutortip
    typedef UINT(WINAPI* EnumEnabledLayoutOrTipFunc)(LPCWSTR pszUserReg, LPCWSTR pszSystemReg, LPCWSTR pszSoftwareReg, LAYOUTORTIPPROFILE* pLayoutOrTipProfile, UINT uBufLength);
    static EnumEnabledLayoutOrTipFunc EnumEnabledLayoutOrTip = reinterpret_cast<EnumEnabledLayoutOrTipFunc>(::GetProcAddress(::LoadLibraryA("input.dll"), "EnumEnabledLayoutOrTip"));

    if (!EnumEnabledLayoutOrTip)
        return {};

    const UINT count = EnumEnabledLayoutOrTip(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, 0);

    std::vector<LAYOUTORTIPPROFILE> layouts;
    layouts.resize(count);

    const UINT written = EnumEnabledLayoutOrTip(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, layouts.data(), count);

    CHECK_EQ(count, written);

    return layouts;
}
```

The `LAYOUTORTIPPROFILE.szId` string format of the layout is:

> <LangID>:<KLID>

The string format of the text service profile (IME) is:

> <LangID>:{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tsf/installlayoutortip#remarks).

Comment: Also you can just run `Get-WinUserLanguageList` in PowerShell :)