# Safe KLID For 'Custom' Keyboard Layout?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-10, custom-keyboard, keyboard-layout

I need to install several 'custom' keyboard layouts on Windows 10.
These are not MKLC generated layouts.

What is a 'safe' KLID to use for my layouts?

axxxxxxx seems to be used by MKLC.
Dxxxxxxx seems to be utilized by the Layouts PreLoad / Substitues

I have several keyboard layouts to install, I.e, ????0409, ????0407, ????040e, .....

Any ideas for a relatively 'safe' value for '????' ?

I am concerned about running into some one else's keyboard layout.

Thanks

Comment: This question seems to be a continuation of the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64995173/how-to-create-a-list-of-keyboards-extract-klid-from-hkl).  What is the difference between ????0409 and 00000409 obtained by `GetKeyboardLayoutName`?

Comment: It is NOT a continuation. Look in tout registry. Anything ending with '0409' is an English based layout, 0000409 (KBDUS.Dll), 0010409 (KBDDV.Dll), 00020409 (KBDUSX.Dll), and so no. These are just the standards installed by windows. a0000409 would be a 'Custom' layout created within MKLC. dxxx0409 seems to be reserved for the Substitutes. I am afraid of installing my layouts with a KLID of say '01000409' and later finding this collides with some existing keyboard layout scheme. Am I being clear?

Comment: There is no document indicating that a custom keyboard layout like '01000409' will be used. According to the layout of the registry, KLID will be increased according to the needs of other languages. So there are two possibilities. The first is that in a long time in the future, Microsoft may occupy this position because of language needs. The second possibility is that third-party tools may use this location.

Comment: Yes strive. That is obvious to me. Looking at the high words it seems Microsoft utilizes from 0000 to 0015 on a standard install. d000 seems to be utilized for Substitutes. a000 is utilized by MKLC with an additional 'Layout Id' registry setting in the key. Yes there is no documentation (which his my problem). There seems to me no rhyme nor reason to the usage (I.e, 00010407 is German IBM, 00010409 is US Dvorak not US IBM). I believe that the final result of my question will be that no-body knows.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Looks like you can use `1`..`9` or `c` or `f` hex as prefix. Next three digits can be used as counter.

Long answer: **KLID** — a keyboard layout identifier.... The KLID can be retrieved for the currently selected keyboard layout in a thread through the [GetKeyboardLayoutName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardlayoutnamew) API (note the pswzKLID parameter), though that is not true of any other selected or installed keyboard layout. Every keyboard layout on the system has one of these. Each KLID is 32 bits (thus 8 hex digits), and they can all be found in the registry as the subkeys under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\`. The bottom half of the KLID is a LANGID, and the top half is something device-specific. By convention, the first hex digit is usually as follows:

- **0** — Most keyboard layouts
- **a** — Keyboard layouts defined by [MSKLC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134)
- **b** — Keyboard layouts defined by [KbdEdit](http://www.kbdedit.com/)
- **d** — Some non-CJK input methods that have been defined by the Text Services Framework (note: reported to me; I have never seen one of these!)
- **e** — CJK input methods, also known as [IMM32 IMEs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/input-method-manager) ([deprecated and not working since Windows 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/input-method-editor-requirements#ime-must-be-compatible-with-windows-apps))

Source: http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/04/17/409032.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear which ID you have in mind.  The KLID itself is not “associated to the layout”; it is associated to “the installation of a layout on a particular system”.  Hence it should be determined at the installation time.

In short: the top word of KLID *is just an ID*.  It should not conflict¹⁾ with other IDs on the particular system — otherwise it is arbitrary.

> ¹⁾ At least on Windows 7, the top word remains the same when the keyboard is enabled several times under different languages.  So there should be *no conflicts between high words*, as opposed to “no conflict of complete 32-bit IDs”.

Starting with Windows 8, the non-conflicting ID should be chosen at installation time.  See the details [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75932692/developed-a-windows-keyboard-layout-dll-but-not-loaded-no-error-message/76030384#76030384) — also see my comment to it.