# Developed a Windows keyboard layout DLL but not loaded, no error message

Tags: windows, dll, windows-11, keyboard-layout

I developed a "keyboard layout DLL" for Windows but I cannot have it loaded and got no error message. I wonder how to troubleshoot this.

There is some sample code for keyboard layouts in https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/input/layout

The idea is simple: Create a DLL which exports a function named `KbdLayerDescriptor`. This function only returns the address of a structure which describes the keyboard. This data structure contains pointers to other structures, etc.

Simple in principle. However, the keyboard layout is never loaded, without error message. There must be something missing but I do not know what.

Here are my investigations.

Step 1: I started from the sample `kbdfr` in the above repo and made a few modifications to make sure I can characterize the new keyboard. I copied the generated DLL in `C:\Windows\System32`. When trying to select the keyboard in the System Settings, the new keyboard is not listed. There was no further explanation in the sample repo.

Step 2: Searching the registry, I found that all keyboards layouts are referenced in `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts]`. So, I added an entry for my new keyboard. This time, I can see it in the system settings. However, when I select it, the keyboard is not active. The previous layout (the French one) remains active. Even when I remove the French layout and only keep my new layout in the settings, the keyboard is still the French one.

Step 3: I browsed all processes and their mapped DLL's, searching which one had the keyboard layouts. I found two instances of `ctfmon.exe` which had `KBDFR.DLL` mapped (this is the standard French keyboard). If I switch to a US layout in the System Settings, I can see that `ctfmon.exe` immediately unmaps `KBDFR.DLL` and maps `KBDUS.DLL`. So, inspecting `ctfmon.exe` is a valid clue about which keyboard is active. If I select my new keyboard layout, `ctfmon.exe` keeps `KBDFR.DLL` and ignores my DLL. This explains why the new layout is not active.

Step 4: I copied a valid working keyboard DLL from a Windows virtual machine running on a Mac. Because of the differences in keyboards, the "Parallels Desktop" hypervisor installs Mac keyboard layouts in the virtual machine. These layouts are not present in Windows by default and they work correctly (I use them in the VM on Mac). They were installed in the VM through the installer of the "Parallels Tools". I do not know exactly what this installer does, in addition to copying the DLL's in `System32`. I copied this DLL and the associated registry entry from the VM on Mac to the target Windows 11 PC (not on a Mac). In the System Settings, I can see the Parallels keyboard for Mac. However, when I select it, the layout does not work and `ctfmon.exe` keeps `KBDFR.DLL`. Same symptom as my layout DLL.

So, the problem does not seem to be in my keyboard DLL but in the way it is installed on the system, because the Parallels layout which works on a VM where it was properly installed no longer works on a system where it was just copied (with its registry entries).

The classical `regsvr32` is useless here since these KBD DLL's are not servers. Running `regsvr32` on any of them raises an error about absent server entry point (seems normal).

Step 5: I tried to overwrite an existing DLL (`KBDGR.DLL`, the German layout) with my DLL to see if it would work when selecting the German layout. However, I get a "Permission Denied" error when trying to overwrite `KBDGR.DLL`, even using an Administrator account. There is probably something with the "trusted installer" here.

EDIT(1): Step 6: I applied the same ACL on my DLL as other keyboards without better result (Get-All kbdus.dll | Set-All kbdmine.dll in Powershell). My DLL is now owned by TrustedInstaller. But it is still not mapped.

EDIT(2): Step 7: In the `KbdLayerDescriptor` function of my DLL, before returning the data structure address, as a test, it creates a temporary text file and writes the path of the exe of the process which invokes it. The file is created when I select the language in the system settings and the process is `C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe`. So, the System Settings app loads the DLL, calls its entry point and unloads it. However, the keyboard does not appear in the language bar and is never loaded by `ctfmon.exe`.

Additional notes:

- Of course, I searched online but only found zillions of obvious and useless hints on Windows keyboards...
- My code and a few tools are available here: https://github.com/lelegard/winkbdlayouts . Given the way a keyboard layout DLL works, it is easy to load one and inspect all the returned structures. So, I developed a tool to reverse-engineer an existing keyboard layout DLL and generate the corresponding C source file for an exact copy. Thus, it is easy to modify any available DLL. But, this does not solve the installation issue.

So, my question is: what are the necessary steps to make sure a personally-developed keyboard layout DLL is properly used?

Comment: Does your DLL work if you register it using KbdSoft's [KbdEdit tool](http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/file_register_layout_dll_file.html)?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134

Comment: @HansPassant, the MS keyboard layout editor no longer works in Windows 11. The editor itself works but, after installing the generated package, the new keyboard is not working. All symptoms are the same as with my own keyboard definitions from source. So, the problem is more general. There is no identified solution.

Comment: @BenVoigt, the KbdEdit tool is not free and the "DLL layout files cannot be registered with the system" in the demo version (kbdedit.com/demo.html).

Comment: As far as I know, the normal way of “using” a layout-DLL does not include “loading it” (as an executable file — this would be a security nightmare — but see Stuxnet!).  The kernel loads it in memory (for reading, not execution) and “manually” runs fixups on the image., and finds the tables.  (Only the applications which want to scan “the stomak of the layout” would “really” load the DLL.)

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to find the solution by myself. I documented the explanations here: https://github.com/lelegard/winkbdlayouts#declaring-a-keyboard-layout-on-windows

Comment: To see a programmatic way to find an appropriate “Layout Id”, [run `examples/raw_keys_via_api.pl` with the `U 1` flag](https://metacpan.org/dist/UI-KeyboardLayout/view/lib/UI/KeyboardLayout.pm#Console-applications-cannot-detect-when-a-keypress-may-be-interpreted-as-a-%E2%80%9Ccommand%E2%80%9D).