# get language locale id

Tags: javascript, localization, locale

How can I get user language locale id?
I can retrieved the language locale name by using `navigator.browserLanguage` but how can I retrieve the ID?

For example, if user `navigator.browserLanguage` is en-US I want to get 1033

Comment: @dfsq I have a legacy code that using a GetLocale function from VBscript and uses this code for settings purposes

Answer (score 0):

This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192856/959850) suggests as follows.

You may take the information from the horse's mouth, i.e. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx, and copy-pasted it (through Excel) into a .properties file like this:

```
1078 = Afrikaans - South Africa
1052 = Albanian - Albania
1118 = Amharic - Ethiopia
1025 = Arabic - Saudi Arabia
5121 = Arabic - Algeria 
...
```

(You can download the file [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2896691/stack/lcid-codes.properties) if you have similar needs.)

You can probably create an object with keys and quickly access them when required.

**Disclaimer**: this really is a minimalistic, "dummy" way of doing it yourself in JavaScript, and obviously keeping (and maintaining) a copy of the LCID mapping information in your own code base is not very elegant. (On the other hand, neither would you want to include a huge library jar or do anything overly complicated just for this simple mapping.) So despite this answer, feel free to post more elegant solutions or existing libraries if you know of anything like that.

**Off-topic**: `navigator.browserLanguage` is IE only. You would be better off using `navigator.userLanguage || navigator.language`, in the browser.